# AWS SFTP with custom identity providers, but the template doesn't work

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, sftp, aws-transfer-family

I want to create a sftp server that the user and access with BOTH username/password and ssh token.

I am following this tutorial to create a customized identity provider

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/custom-identity-provider-users.html

In the section of Lambda function templates, I choose to use "Classic (Cognito) stack template".

My problem is, when I upload this template to Cloudformation, I get this error:

> IF: CreateServer error

Can anyone point out if I missed something, or this template doesn't work. If it is the template problem, can anyone help fix it?

Comment: You might want to provide some more context/info, looks like the Transfer server is failing, but can't infer much more with just that

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have confirmed with AWS that they had bug with their template. But I am not sure if it is fixed now.

Comment: Glad to hear that, of course, this is a "take it or leave it" scenario, but my advice in those cases is to get their base template, strip it down of any "bloat" and start adding things back again, something like strip all of Cognito and lambda from the template, just the server; then add lambda, fix permissions, etc and have a lambda that always sends a successful auth; then add Cognito, and modify your lambda appropriately, this will make the debugging process way simpler, as well as providing you with a system that kinda works all the time. I hope this helps!